# Creating a function similar to a Bayesian Belief Network

Tags: bayesian, bayesian-network, python

If I have a list of outcomes to a scenario like:

```
(Fast / Slow), (close to home / far from home), (car, truck), (daytime / nighttime)
```

and a list of outcomes:

```
Slow / Close to Home / Car / Daytime
Fast / Far From Home / Truck / Nighttime
Slow / Close to Home / Car / Nighttime
Fast / Close to Home / Truck / Daytime
Slow / Close to Home / Car / Daytime
```

And I wanted to create something similar to a Bayesian Belief Network where I could say, 'Given that it was `far from home`, what is the probability it was each of `Slow / Fast / Car / Truck / Daytime`, what would be the best way to create a formula to provide this output?

I am familiar with Bayesian Belief Networks, but I would imagine there are other ways to create this formula, preferably in python.  Is there an accepted technique for creating this sort of a function that is easy to reproduce algorithmically?  My issue is BBN's are bulky and I'm not very familiar with setting them up algorithmically from a given input.

If BBN is the best solution, what is the preferred technique for establishing one?